# Associating an array with a variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm now learning a little about templates and templates in C++11, C++14 and C++1z. I'm trying to write a variadic class template with an inside class that will associate an `int` to every template argument - and have a `constexpr` method that returns its array representation.

Let's say that I have ensured that the template cannot receive two of the same type as an argument. I was thinking about doing it somewhat like this:

```
template <typename... Types>
struct MyVariadicTemplate {
    //we know that all types in Types... are different
    template <int... Values> 
    struct MyInnerTemplate {
        //I need to make sure that sizeof...(Values) == sizeof...(Types)
        constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Values)> to_array() {
            std::array<int, sizeof...(Values)> result = {Values...};
            return result;
            // this is only valid since C++14, as far as I know
        }
    };
};
```

this code should be valid (if it's not, I'd love to know why). Now, I'd like to add another inner template:

```
template <typedef Type>
struct AnotherInnerTemplate {};
```

that has a `public typedef`, which represents `MyInnerTemplate` with one on the position of `Type` in `Types...` and zeros elsewhere - and here I'm lost. I don't know how to proceed

I would appreciate any hint on how that can be done - and if I'm heading towards the wrong direction, I hope somebody can give me a hint on how to do that.

Comment: I don't understand  the `typedef` of `AnotherInnerTemplate` could you show an example

Answer (score 1):

```
  template <int size, int... Values> struct AnotherImpl {
    using Type = typename AnotherImpl<size - 1, Values..., 0>::Type;
  };

  template <int... Values> struct AnotherImpl<0, Values...> {
    using Type = Inner<Values...>;
  };

  template <class T> struct Another {
    using Type = typename AnotherImpl<sizeof...(Types) - 1, 1>::Type;
  };
```

Full:

```
template <class... Types> struct My {

  template <int... Values> struct Inner {
    constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Values)> to_array() {
      return std::array<int, sizeof...(Values)>{Values...};
    }
  };

  template <int size, int... Values> struct AnotherImpl {
    using Type = typename AnotherImpl<size - 1, Values..., 0>::Type;
  };

  template <int... Values> struct AnotherImpl<0, Values...> {
    using Type = Inner<Values...>;
  };

  template <class T> struct Another {
    using Type = typename AnotherImpl<sizeof...(Types) - 1, 1>::Type;
  };
};

auto main() -> int {
  My<int, float, char>::Another<int>::Type s;

  auto a = s.to_array();

  for (auto e : a) {
    cout << e << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
1 0 0
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: This is **almost** what I want. I want to be able to call:

My<int, float, char>::Another<int>::Type s;

and after that to do what you have done with the same result

Comment: @Jytug no problem just make Another a template. See edit

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like this.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename NeedleT, typename... HaystackTs>
constexpr auto get_type_index_mask() noexcept
{
  constexpr auto N = sizeof...(HaystackTs);
  return std::array<bool, N> {
    (std::is_same<NeedleT, HaystackTs>::value)...
  };
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t ffs(const std::array<T, N>& array) noexcept
{
  for (auto i = std::size_t {}; i < N; ++i)
    {
      if (array[i])
        return i;
    }
  return N;
}

int
main()
{
  const auto mask = get_type_index_mask<float, bool, int, float, double, char>();
  for (const auto& bit : mask)
    std::cout << bit;
  std::cout << "\n";
  std::cout << "float has index " << ffs(mask) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
00100
float has index 2
```

The magic happens in the parameter pack expansion

```
(std::is_same<NeedleT, HaystackTs>::value)...
```

where you test each type in `HaystackTs` against `NeedleT`. You might want to apply `std::decay` to either type if you want to consider, say, `const int` and `int` the same type.